Stock nodes and trading platform
On a dating app a man asked me to buy crypto currency and to trade stocks during nodes.
Is this a problem?
I had a small profit until now.
But he wants me to invest more and if I don't do it he will disappear from me.
Could I risk something trading nodes of stocks?
Thanks


Could I risk something trading nodes of stocks?

Yes, you could risk the money you put in.
This is a scam. There are no profits, there's no man, and any money you've already "invested" is long gone. You can confirm that by trying to withdraw and noticing how instead of getting your money back you are being asked to pay the various non-existent "fees" and "taxes".
See also "Romance Scam" and "Advance Fee Scam". Or the many various different similar questions on this topic.
